# Jquery dom element referencing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have developed a code to add,edit and delete new tags.
I have successfully added new tags to the list.

I try to delete tag by selecting the *`<li>`* elements . When i select a tag i can only select the first three tags as they are the initial tags when the DOM element **.tag-list-items** gets   referenced. Is there any way i can update the element referenced so that it contains all the *`<li>`* elements which i have added ?.

Comment: Please find the code in below link  https://jsfiddle.net/eL3sgxa1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eL3sgxa1/1/)
The _tagSel() is called when the list item is added. Also, you need to use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` inside the click event.

Comment: Thanks for the answer varun.

Answer (score 2):

Have to use `$(".tag-list-items").on('click', 'li', tagOperations._tagDel)` and the future elements will also get the `tagOperations._tagDel` listener. More info is [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)